# Troubleshoot a simple checksum comparison script

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have created a simple checksum script that checks a checksum of a file called tecu.a2l and compares it to a few .md5 files - ensuring that they all have the exact same checksum whenever this script is running.

To make things easier to understand:

Lets say i have tecu.a2l with the checksum 1x2x3x. So the md5 files (if generated correctly) should have the same checksum (1x2x3x). If one of the md5 files has a different checksum than what the latest tecu.a2l has it will give an error.

Hopefully the code might fill in the blanks if you did not quite understand my description.

```
import hashlib
import dst_creator_constants as CONST
import Tkinter

path_a2l = 'C:<path>\tecu.a2l'
md5 = hashlib.md5()
blocks = 65565
with open(path_a2l, 'rb') as a2l:
    readA2L = a2l.read(blocks)
    generatedMD5 = md5.hexdigest()
    print "stop1"

ihx_md5_files = CONST.PATH_DELIVERABLES_DST
for file in ihx_md5_files:
    print "stop2"
    if file.endswith('.md5'):
        print "stop3"
        readMD5 = file.read()
        if compare_checksums:
            print "Yes"
            # Add successful TkInter msg here
        else:
            print "No" 
            # Add error msg here


def compare_checksums(generatedMD5, readMD5):
    if generatedMD5 == readMD5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When i run this script, nothing happens. No messages, nothing. If i type in `python checksum.py` into cmd - it returns no message. So i put in some `print` statements to see what could be the issue. The issue is, that `stop3` is never shown in the command prompt - which means that the problem has something to do with `if file.endswith('.md5'):` statement.

I have no idea why it's the culprit as I have used this `file.endswith()` statement on a previous script I wrote in relation to this and there it has worked so I am turning to you.

Comment: If it really should work, really, really, then maybe the problem is somewhere else. Can you show us the definition, or a print, of `CONST.PATH_DELIVERABLES_DST` ?

Comment: Also, `compare_checksums` is a reference to a function. You have to use `compare_checksums()` to call it.

Comment: It's just a path just as `path_a2l` I can as simply manually add the dir as `ihx_md5_files` and i did.. but it did not help. I've also used the same path definition before so there is no problem with it. adding parenthesis did not help CMD never writes `stop3` unfortunately.

Comment: But you process it as a list, not a path. Instead of printing "stop2", try printing file.

Comment: I found the issue - the current working dir was different. Before the 
`for file in ihx_md5_files:` statement I simply added `os.chdir(CONST.PATH_DELIVERABLES_DST)` and now it's working :)
Thanks @Austin Hastings I appreciate your efforts to help me. I guess you were on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a hash object. Your file stays in your `readA2L` variable. Also, your file may be larger than the 65565 byte buffer you allow it. Try to update your hasher like the function below and let us know what the result is.

```
import hashlib as h
from os.path import isfile

hasher = h.md5()
block_size = 65536


def get_hexdigest(file_path, hasher, block_size):

    if isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            buf = f.read(block_size)

            while len(buf) > 0:
                # Update the hasher until the entire file has been read
                hasher.update(buf)
                buf = f.read(block_size)

        digest = hasher.hexdigest()
    else:
        return None
    return digest
```